# Compute averages of column in list of pandas data frames and plot distribution

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, seaborn

I have a list of pandas dataframes, `dflist`, and I would like to plot the average distribution from a subset of a single column in the data frames in `dflist`.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 6) , columns=list('ABCXYZ'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 6) , columns=list('ABCXYZ'))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 6) , columns=list('ABCXYZ'))

dflist = [df1,df2,df3]

for i in np.arange(3):
    sns.distplot(dflist[i][70:90]['A'], bins=None, hist=True, kde=True, rug=False)
plt.show()
```

This returns a nice plot:
[image]

However, what I want is an average distribution of these three columns in the data frames so that there is just one line and not three. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `dflist` only has three elements? I think you mean `dflist[i][70:90]['A']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dflist` is a list of three elements. Your order of indexing in the line:

```
dflist[70:90][i]['A']
```

is wrong as it attempts to index through the `DataFrame` and filter the rows first, causing the `IndexError`.

This indexing will work as intended when written as:

```
dflist[i][70:90]['A']
```

which will select the `DataFrame`, from `df1` to `df3`, first, then filter the rows of data.

For your second question on how to produce the average distribution, how about the following?

```
avg_df = pd.concat([df['A'] for df in dflist], axis=1)                          
avg_df["mean"] = avg_df.mean(axis=1)                                            

sns.distplot(avg_df.loc[avg_df.index[70:90], 'mean'], bins=None, hist=True, kde=True, rug=False)
plt.show()
```

This code works by producing a new `avg_df` `DataFrame` by joining the 'A' columns from every `DataFrame` in your `dflist`. It then calculates the mean along the rows of this `DataFrame`. Finally, it indexes `avg_df` to keep only the selected rows (`70:90`) and the 'mean' column.
[image: Average distribution]

Comment: Thank you! I will edit the question above since there is still the remaining component of getting the average distribution.

Comment: @JAG2024 Updated with an answer for your second question.